# Clarification on i18n implementation for Chromium Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For months, I've been trying to find ways to implement localization in my Chromium Extension. Most of which ended up breaking the HTML side where the options are at. Recently, I may have found one that works without breaking anything on HTML and JS, but I'd like some clarification if this approach is good.

This is part of the code in the `i18n.js` file.

```
document.getElementById("button_save").innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage("button_save");
```

And the language changes when I change the browser language.

Will there be any issues going for this method for setting i18n? Thanks.

Comment: There'll be no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but allow me to suggest you an approach that is much more reliable and maintainable than selecting every element manually with `getElementById` or similar functions (specially if your page changes).

You can add a `data-locale-msg` attribute to the elements that need to be localized, like this:

```
<input type="button" data-locale-msg="button_save"/>

<div data-locale-msg="something">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Then, in your `i18n.js` script, all you need to do is:

```
// Get all the elements with data-locale-msg="..."
let els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-locale-msg]');

// Fill the elements with the right localized messages:
els.forEach(el => el.innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage(el.dataset.localeMsg));
```

Simple as that, no manual element selection needed!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've implemented this in the extension and it works very well. Less code on the JavaScript side. By the way, could you explain how `el.dataset.localMsg` works?

Comment: @captain_watanabe attributes starting with `data-` are special and can be easily accessed with JavaScript using the `.dataset` property of the element. So if you have something like `data-foo-bar-baz="123"` you can access it from JS with `el.dataset.fooBarBaz`.

Comment: I see. Thank you again for the explaining it